# How to improve my code and display results properly from API response in react

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks

I have a working code but need to improve it which is what I am struggling with.

I am making an API call to an endpoint in my react project, the API returns a response like below for two different state, when it returns an error or a success.

API response when there is an error

```
singleEvent {error: 'Invalid event'}
```

API response when it is successful

```
{event: {
  activeStatus: true,
  address: "Crescent City, CA, USA",
  date: "2022-09-22T11:50:47.832Z",
   ...
}}
```

The issue I have here is that, in my JSX, I have a conditional rendering that displays an error when the API returns an error and also the template when the API is successful.

Since the request is an async on, the error response is always first returned which leads to the user seeing the error screen for a short while and then the proper template, I need a way to eliminate that.

Here is the JSX

```
  if (
    singleEvent?.error === "Invalid event"
  ) {
    return <Custom404 />;
  }

  return (
    <div className="app-main-layout-container mt-80">
        <div>rest of the content</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You didn't post the code doing the fetch, but generally there is a way to know if the request has in fact completed. Check for that before rendering content - the usual thing to do would be to display a spinner while loading.

Comment: Here's one of my toys using react query and checking isLoading https://codesandbox.io/s/react-usequery-dynamic-ql4y6

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check for when the api request is still in progress. If the api request is still in progress, show a loader and then when the api request ends, you can show the appropriate result.

Comment: How can I achieve this?

Comment: What are you using for fetch api results? depending upon the library there are various ways to do so. Someone has already commented about react-query. If I know which lib you are using, I can add it to my answer.